# How to access path data of an svg file and use it as google-maps marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, vue.js, svg

I want to use custom svg icon as google-maps marker.

I got this file:

```
<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="510px" height="510px" viewBox="0 0 510 510">
    <g
        stroke="black"
        stroke-width="10"
        fill="white"
    >
        <path d="M497.25,357v-51l-204-127.5V38.25C293.25,17.85,275.4,0,255,0c-20.4,0-38.25,17.85-38.25,38.25V178.5L12.75,306v51
        l204-63.75V433.5l-51,38.25V510L255,484.5l89.25,25.5v-38.25l-51-38.25V293.25L497.25,357z"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I don't know much about svg but I managed to use the svg file's path attribute `d` as a string and it works fine:

```
mounted() {
    new this.google.maps.Marker({
         position: this.flight.position,
         flight: this.flight,
         map: this.map,
         icon: {
             path: "M497.25,357v-51l-204-the-string-goes-on-and-on",
             scale: .04,
             fillColor: '#FFFFFF',
             fillOpacity: 1,
             strokeWeight: 1,
             rotation: this.flight.trueTrack,
             anchor: new this.google.maps.Point(250, 400)
         }
    })
 }
```

But I want to avoid using looong string for `path`. Is it, for example, possible to import the svg file from asset folder and reference its path attribute `d` as a variable?

Pseudocode (I have no idea what I'm doing):

```
import svgFile from '../assets/file.svg';

const path = document.querySelector("path");
const d = path.getAttribute("d");

(...)

mounted() {
    new this.google.maps.Marker({
         position: this.flight.position,
         flight: this.flight,
         map: this.map,
         icon: {
             path: d,
             (...)
         }
    })
 }
```

Or am I completely wrong and there is another, better way of eliminating hardcoded strings in `path`? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I eventually got it.

First of all the file has to be imported as text:

```
import svgPlane from '!raw-loader!../assets/airplane.svg';
```

To do that I had to install raw-loader:

```
npm install raw-loader --save-dev
```

Then I had to parse it using `DOMParser` and reference the data just like a DOM element:

```
  mounted() {
    const parser = new DOMParser();
    const svgPath = parser
      .parseFromString(svgPlane, "image/svg+xml")
      .querySelector('path')
      .getAttribute('d')

    new this.google.maps.Marker({
      position: this.flight.position,
      flight: this.flight,
      map: this.map,
      icon: {
        path: svgPath,
        (...)
      }
    })
  }
```

No magic numbers! That's the answer I was looking for.

Comment: Thanks for updating us, glad to hear you found a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

In vanilla JavaScript you can just add the values in the marker's icon property as follows:

```
  const path = document.querySelector("path");
  const d = path.getAttribute("d");

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: {lat: -25.344, lng: 131.036},
    map: map,
    icon: {
      path: d
    }
  });
```

So you should be able to do the same in Vue via import.

Comment: Oh I see, then my assumption is wrong although the same logic applies?

Comment: @evan I was thinking about modifying the svg markup to have all the required attributes like `stroke`, `fill` etc. (take a look at my edited question) but I failed when I tried to implement rotation which comes in as a prop.

Comment: Thanks, I've just edited my answer. You're on the right track. SVG have no rotation attribute but if you can get it via props then I don't see the issue. The above code works. Yours in vue should as well?

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
let iconpath = '../assets/file.svg'; 
console.log(iconpath);//Conform url is correct.

mounted() {
    new this.google.maps.Marker({
     position: this.flight.position,
     flight: this.flight,
     map: this.map,
     icon: iconpath,
 })  }
```

Comment: I have a lot of icon properties which I need to modify using props (like `rotation` or `anchor`). I'm not sure how to obtain that in svg markup or is it possible at all (I included my attempt in edited question).